# How to get the value of dynamically created tablerow?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to get the value of the input-field that was dynamically created in function rijToevoegen().

Somehow I keep getting undefined, what am I doing wrong?

These are my functions I use:

```
//adding the tablerow
function rijToevoegen(columnarray, fieldarray, tabelnaam){
    var columns = columnarray;
    var fields = fieldarray;
    var row = '<tr>';

    for(i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
        row += "<td class=columns[i]><input type='text' id=fields[i]></td>";
        console.log(fields[i]);
    }
    row += '</tr>';
    $(tabelnaam).append(row);

}


  //getting the value
  $('#vs_opslaan').click(function() {
    var columns = ['naamkolom','locatiekolom','hostkolom','cpukolom','memorykolom','oskolom','hddkolom','spkolom','usernamekolom','passwordkolom','ipkolom','domeinkolom','opmerkingenkolom'];
    var velden = ['naamveld','locatieveld','hostveld','cpuveld','memoryveld','osveld','hddveld','spveld','usernameveld','passwordveld','ipveld','domeinveld','opmerkingenveld'];
    var response_array = [];
    for(i=0;i<velden.length;i++){
        var rij = $('#velden[i]').val();
        console.log(rij);
        //response_array += $().value;
    }
    //console.log(response_array);

});
```

Help is always appreciated!

Ramon

Comment: How do you call the function? I assume you pass it columns and velden, but you don't say. Also it could be useful if you added what the two console.log loops print.

Comment: I believe I found the problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are referencing the arrays they cannot be inside the string or they will be set as literal strings.

When you put `"<td class=columns[i]><input type='text' id=fields[i]></td>"`
the class and id contain literal strings `columns[i]` and `fields[i]`
What you want is to concatenate your array values with the markup. 
`"<td class=" + columns[i] + "><input type='text' id=" + fields[i] + "></td>"`

This also applies to when you are doing the jquery selector.
So instead of `$('#velden[i]').val();` you want `$('#' + velden[i]).val();`

Comment: Dude you are a hero, I tried similar things, but I did either 1 " too much or not enough of em, thanks for solving my simple problem haha

Comment: I knew this was the problem somehow, but just couldn't solve it, feels stupid haha